# Renaming a repo wrecks travis

Tags: travis-ci

I renamed my repo on github and now everything is broken. It started off with the "build status" image being broken.

From desperation I revoked travis's github access to my account. I wanted to delete my travis account to start fresh but that's impossible it seems :(

I tried to stop CI on my one repo and I got this error:

> An error happened when we tried to alter settings on GitHub. It may be caused by API restrictions, please review and add your authorized Orgs

I'd love to, but travis's website doesn't seem to have a "reauth" button.

I think my [travis](https://travis-ci.org/profile/ubershmekel) is in limbo :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Fixed it, just had to sign out and sign in to travis. That re-auths travis from github because it uses github sign-in.

Maybe there should be a button for that in the main travis UI?

Comment: Yep, this fixed it

Comment: There is (now?) a button for that in the Travis CI user interface: click the "Sync Account" button.

Comment: @BrunoRijsman That button never works. Signing out and in is the only way(in my experience).

Comment: @NelsonGon neither worked for me - also had to sign out and in in order for it to work.